# Does Constructor dot newInstance use reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

Let `MyClass` be the class represented by this java code:

```
public MyClass 
{
    private String foo;
    private Integer bar;
    public MyClass(byte[] contents) { ... }
}
```

Let `myConstructor` be the following Constructor instance:

```
Constructor myConstructor = MyClass.class.getDeclaredConstructor(byte[].class);
```

My question is the following

Does this code use reflection?

```
byte[]  contents   = new byte[]{0,1,2};
MyClass myInstance = myConstructor.newInstance(contents);
```

or is equivalent, once that `myConstructor` is instantiated, to the following code?

```
byte[] contents = new byte[]{0,1,2};
MyClass myInstance = new MyClass(contents);
```

The equivalence relation I'm thinking about is that `.newInstance(byte[] contents)` access directly to the constructor in the same way as the `new` and the only reflection operation is finding the constructor.

Kind regards

Comment: `MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod(byte[].class);`: is that valid? Or did you mean `getDeclaredConstructor(byte[].class)`?

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo, I meant `declaredConstructor`

Comment: Constructor is in the package java.lang.reflect. Yes, this uses reflection. It calls a constructor without using `new`, in a dynamic rather than static way, and the compiler thus can't make sure that this constructor invocation is valid. You need to catch a whole bunch of exceptions because this call might be incorrect. That's reflection.

Comment: @JBNizet Is a performance penalty then? or if I have that Constructor object already cached is there a performance penalty for just calling the constructor? thanks

Comment: Are you calling that statement / logic like 1 million times a second? If not: don't worry about performance.

Comment: `getDeclaredConstructor` is pretty slow, so if you need to call it multiple times then just cache that constructor instance, executing it is pretty fast, and can be even faster with MethodHandle, but cache is enough in near every case in terms of performance.